# The rootScope variable applying two seconds late for ng-if

Tags: angularjs

The Below code is app.js

```
var app = angular.module('inkwiry', [
    'ngSanitize',
    'ui.select',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ngCookies',
    'oc.lazyLoad',
    'ngAnimate',
    'ui.bootstrap-slider',
    'duScroll',
    'ui.router',
    'ngResource',
    'jQueryScrollbar',
    'angular-confirm',
    'ngCkeditor',
    'ngScrollbars',
    'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination',
    'ngDragDrop',
    'fixed.table.header',
    'stripe'
]);

app.run(function($rootScope, $state, $location, $window) {

    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        $rootScope.loader = {
            loading: true
        };

        console.log('app start');
    });

    $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeSuccess", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState) {
        $rootScope.loader = {
            loading: false
        };

        console.log('app end');
    });
});
```

2) index.html

```
<div id="overlay" class="overlay" ng-if="loader.loading">
    <div class="loading" id="loading">
        <img src="external/img/ripple.svg">
        <h1>Loading, Please wait...</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried so many ways but still same issues in local its working fine, But in server its coming late.
The status of the variable is changing but its applying to div after 2 to 3 seconds.
I have removed ngAnimate also still same issue.
Can some help.

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to achieve. You're setting `$rootScope.loader.loading` to true/false, but in you're template you're using ng-if with `spinloader`!?

Comment: Sorry for that that should be loader.loading not spinloader

Comment: What is your problem? where is the controller, and the route definitions? You look to be using ui-router, what are you resolving on the route change that is causing problems?